# Counting rows without duplicates MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table such as the following

```
id_profile, id_user
1         , 5
1         , 4
1         , 4
1         , 4
2         , 1
2         , 5
2         , 2
```

I'm trying to count id_user but I have to eliminate duplicates. So, I want a result like

```
id_profile, count
1         , 2
2         , 3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `count distinct`:

```
select id_profile, count(distinct id_user) as count
from tablename
group by id_profile
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub-query to filter distinct values and then use count, group by on that if that's easier to understand.

```
SELECT id_profile, COUNT(id_user)
    FROM(SELECT DISTINCT id_profile,id_user FROM tablename)
    GROUP BY id_profile
```